# How to avoid name collisions of css class names

Tags: css, html

I am writting a web page using css classes of PURE by Yahoo.
In detail, it is really not an independent web page but a part of a web page of some site. And I have no contact to the company running the site.

When I tested my part as an independent web page, it looked fine. Though when I tested the part within the parent web page, I noticed that the css did not work at all.

The only reason I can assume for the errors is name collisions. For example, my part uses class "header" defined in PURE. I guess the class name is used by programmers of the parent web page.

If my assumption is correct, could you help me to avoid name collisions of css class names.

Comment: choose a class name, search through all the files , if there is none, you can proceed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using BEM methodology (try reading this http://getbem.com/introduction/) for this purpose.

Let's say you call your app (or widget or website, as you wish) `MyPersonalApp`. Name your class accordingly like in this following example:

```
<div class="MyPersonalApp">
    <div class="MyPersonalApp__container">
        <p class="MyPersonalApp__text">
            Hello world.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

However this code will not ensure that you will run into a conflict with the parent website, so try to pick as unique name as you can. When I write widgets or embedded apps, I try to pick names like `EmbeddedChatWidgetBySomeCompany` and intentionally use camel casing - as that is usually not what developers use for their class names.